# Find minimum and maximum values of multi-variables function in Python

Tags: python, function, max, min

I have a function and I would like to find its maximum and minimum values. My function is this:

```
fuc = x * (4 - x * y)
```

I have an interval for x [-1, 1] and y [2, 10]. I would like to find a way, limited to this interval, to discover the max and min values of this function.

Comment: This looks more like an optimization problem than a programming problem.

Comment: Since there are no higher powers, the answers are going to be at the endpoints.  The max is (1,2) and the min is (1,10).

Comment: Well, normaly you would use for this its First derivative, Set it to zero and solve for for x and y. In 3d this is approached by partial differentiation

Answer (score 1):

Use [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html):

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

func = lambda x: x[0] * (4 - x[0] * x[1])
x0 = np.array([0, 2])
bounds = [(-1, 1), (2, 10)]
min_val = minimize(func, x0, bounds=bounds).fun
max_val = minimize(lambda x: -func(x), x0, bounds=bounds).fun

print(min_val, max_val)
```

Output:

```
-14.0 -2.0
```

Thank @joni for pointing out that the parameter `bounds` should be used instead of simple constraints.

Comment: Instead of passing simple bounds on the variable as constraints, it's highly recommended to pass them via `bounds`, i.e. `bounds = [(-1, 1), (2, 10)]`. Besides being much more readable, it also makes a difference for some of the algorithms under the hood of scipy's minimize.